# Slimmest OpenID Implementation?

Tags: php, openid

Is there an implementation of OpenID that is under 5K or at least under 10K?

Please format the code with http://beta.phpformatter.com/ with the following settings to get the true size:

> #### Indentation:
>
> Indentation style: `{K&R (One true brace style)}`
>   Indent with: `{Tabs}`
>   Starting indentation: `[1]`
>   Indentation: `[1]`
>
> #### Common:
>
> `[x]` Remove all comments
>   `[x]` Remove empty lines
>   `[x]` Align assignments statements nicely
>   `[ ]` Put a comment with the condition after if, while, for, foreach, declare and catch statements
>
> #### Improvement:
>
> `[x]` Remove lines with just a semicolon (;)
>   `[x]` Make normal comments (//) from perl comments (#)
>   `[x]` Make long opening tag (
>
> #### Brackets:
>
> `[x]` Space inside brackets`- ( )`
>   `[x]` Space inside empty brackets`- ( )`
>   `[x]` Space inside block brackets`- [ ]`
>   `[x]` Space inside empty block brackets`- [ ]`

### Edit:

[Alix Axel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89771/alix-axel) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699124/slimmest-openid-implementation/4699484#4699484) seems great, not perfect but is getting there. BTW: this is 6.4K So it is no longer the smallest, but i'm going through it to clean it up lots more.

```
<?php
    class openID {
        function __construct( $url = null, $realm = null, $return = null, $redirect = true, $verify = false ) {
            $data = array( );
            if ( ( $verify !== true ) && ( self::Value( $_REQUEST, 'openid_mode' ) !== false ) ) {
                if ( strcmp( 'id_res', self::Value( $_REQUEST, 'openid_mode' ) ) === 0 ) {
                    $data[ 'openid.sig' ]          = $_REQUEST[ 'openid_sig' ];
                    $data[ 'openid.mode' ]         = 'check_authentication';
                    $data[ 'openid.signed' ]       = $_REQUEST[ 'openid_signed' ];
                    $data[ 'openid.assoc_handle' ] = $_REQUEST[ 'openid_assoc_handle' ];
                    if ( array_key_exists( 'openid_op_endpoint', $_REQUEST ) === true ) {
                        $data[ 'openid.ns' ] = 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0';
                    }
                    foreach ( explode( ',', self::Value( $_REQUEST, 'openid_signed' ) ) as $value ) {
                        $data[ 'openid.' . $value ] = $_REQUEST[ 'openid_' . str_replace( '.', '_', $value ) ];
                    }
                    if ( preg_match( '~is_valid\s*:\s*true~i', self::CURL( self::__construct( $_REQUEST[ 'openid_identity' ], false, false, false, true ), $data, 'POST' ) ) > 0 ) {
                        return self::Value( $_REQUEST, 'openid_claimed_id', self::Value( $_REQUEST, 'openid_identity' ) );
                    }
                }
            } else if ( ( $result = self::CURL( $url ) ) !== false ) {
                $xml    = self::XML( $result );
                $server = strval( self::XML( $xml, '//xrd/service/uri', 0 ) );
                if ( empty( $server ) === true ) {
                    $server = strval( self::XML( $xml, '//head/link[@rel="openid.server" or @rel="openid2.provider"]/@href', 0 ) );
                }
                if ( self::URL( $server ) === true ) {
                    if ( $redirect === true ) {
                        $realm    = ( isset( $realm ) === true ) ? $realm : sprintf( '%s://%s/', $_SERVER[ "HTTPS" ] ? "https" : "http", $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );
                        $return   = ( isset( $return ) === true ) ? $return : sprintf( '%s://%s', $_SERVER[ "HTTPS" ] ? "https" : "http", $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] );
                        $delegate = ( preg_match( '~http://specs[.]openid[.]net/auth/2[.]0/server~', $result ) > 0 ) ? 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select' : $url;
                        if ( preg_match( '~rel="openid[.]delegate"|<[^>]*Delegate[^>]*>~i', $result ) > 0 ) {
                            $delegate = parent::Value( ph()->Text->Regex( $result, '<([^>]*)Delegate[^>]*>([^>]+)</\1Delegate>', 1 ), 0 );
                            if ( empty( $delegate ) === true ) {
                                $delegate = strval( self::XML( $xml, '//head/link[@rel="openid.delegate"]/@href', 0, $delegate ) );
                            }
                        }
                        if ( preg_match( '~rel="openid2[.]provider"|http://specs[.]openid[.]net/auth/2[.]0~i', $result ) > 0 ) {
                            $data[ 'openid.ns' ] = 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0';
                            if ( preg_match( '~rel="openid2[.]local_id"|<(Local|Canonical)ID[^>]*>~i', $result ) > 0 ) {
                                $delegate = self::Value( self::Regex( $result, '<(Local|Canonical)ID[^>]*>([^>]+)</\1ID>', 1 ), 0 );
                                if ( empty( $delegate ) === true ) {
                                    $delegate = strval( self::XML( $xml, '//head/link[@rel="openid2.local_id"]/@href', 0, $delegate ) );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $data[ 'openid.mode' ]                                                                                = 'checkid_setup';
                        $data[ 'openid.return_to' ]                                                                           = $return;
                        $data[ 'openid.claimed_id' ]                                                                          = $data[ 'openid.identity' ] = $delegate;
                        $data[ 'openid.' . ( ( array_key_exists( 'openid.ns', $data ) === true ) ? 'realm' : 'trust_root' ) ] = $realm;
                        self::Redirect( sprintf( '%s%s%s', $server, ( strpos( $server, '?' ) !== false ) ? '&' : '?', http_build_query( $data, '', '&' ) ) );
                    }
                    return $server;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        function CURL( $url, $data = null, $method = "GET", $options = array( ) ) {
            $result = false;
            if ( ( extension_loaded( "curl" ) === true ) && ( $this->URL( $url ) === true ) ) {
                $curl = curl_init( $url );
                if ( is_resource( $curl ) === true ) {
                    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
                    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
                    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
                    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
                    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                    if ( preg_match( "~^GET$~i", $method ) > 0 ) {
                        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true );
                    } else if ( preg_match( "~^POST$~i", $method ) > 0 ) {
                        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
                        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
                    }
                    $result = curl_exec( $curl );
                    if ( $result !== false ) {
                        curl_close( $curl );
                    }
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }
        function Redirect( $url, $permanent = false ) {
            if ( headers_sent() !== true ) {
                header( "Location: " . $url, true, ( $permanent === true ) ? 301 : 302 );
            }
            exit( );
        }
        function Regex( $string, $pattern, $key = null, $modifiers = null, $flag = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, $default = false ) {
            $matches = array( );
            if ( preg_match_all( "~" . $pattern . "~" . $modifiers, $string, $matches, $flag ) > 0 ) {
                if ( isset( $key ) === true ) {
                    return ( $key === true ) ? $matches : Value( $matches, $key, $default );
                }
                return true;
            }
            return $default;
        }
        function URL( $value ) {
            return (bool) filter_var( $value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL );
        }
        function Value( $data, $key = null, $default = false ) {
            if ( isset( $key ) === true ) {
                foreach ( (array) $key as $value ) {
                    if ( is_object( $data ) === true ) {
                        $data = get_object_vars( $data );
                    }
                    if ( array_key_exists( $value, (array) $data ) !== true ) {
                        return $default;
                    }
                    $data = $data[ $value ];
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
        function XML( $xml, $xpath = null, $key = null, $default = false ) {
            if ( extension_loaded( "SimpleXML" ) === true ) {
                libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
                if ( ( is_string( $xml ) === true ) && ( class_exists( "DOMDocument" ) === true ) ) {
                    $dom = new DOMDocument();
                    if ( $dom->loadHTML( $xml ) === true ) {
                        return $this->XML( simplexml_import_dom( $dom ), $xpath, $key, $default );
                    }
                } else if ( is_object( $xml ) === true ) {
                    if ( isset( $xpath ) === true ) {
                        $xml = $xml->xpath( $xpath );
                        if ( isset( $key ) === true ) {
                            $xml = $this->Value( $xml, $key, $default );
                        }
                    }
                    return $xml;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    new openID( "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" );
?>
```

Comment: Why does it need to be under 10K?

Comment: Because my CMS in about 10K each file, (2 files currently) I want everything to be as slim as I can get it. :)

Comment: My current size of my CMs is 462 and lightopenid minimised to my format gave me 469 lines, It doubles my codebase, I do not what large files being included, Okay I know its not big at all but I want to have the whole project under 30K at the end. Its over 30K already if I add this lightopenid.

Comment: The question stays: why? Do you have a size-limit on some sort of device? Because less bytes doesn't mean "quicker" at all for 'normal' purposes. It's your app and do what you like, but out of curiosity and possibly maybe even avoid a "limit" based on something that's not an issue, i'm also curious about WHY you want it "slim". e.g. : As I see it this is NOT a good way to ensure speed....

Comment: You could always simply roll your own OpenID implementation. So far mine's at 400 LoC (13k with comments/whitespace) and supports association and dumb mode.

Comment: Can't you simply split it up into multiple files?

Comment: Got it down to 14.1 KB after a lit bit of removing unused code. With a little bit more effort I bet you can get it down below 10K. The compressed file is already 9KB but not human readable anymore.

Comment: @JamesM I got lightopenid below the 10K threshold, but got bored ;). I think if you really hard you could get it class to 5K => https://gist.github.com/9742de21ca5f121deab9

Comment: @Time Machaine then that defeats my Goals with ways around them, splitting the functions into multiple files is a waist of requre_once time..

Comment: @Jeff Hubbard: Can you please post your code in an answer ??

Comment: I'm still debugging it/adding proper error handling, plus my plan was to scrap that code after getting it fully working and create a php extension to do it.

Comment: @Jeff Hubbard : Well Can you please post the code in here? When its fully working before you scrap it, please back it up on some site like as an answer and don't delete it :)

Comment: @James You're going about optimization in the exact wrong way. Trying to avoid the time wasted by an `require_once` call? That is so pointless it's staggering. You could eliminate a thousand `require_once` calls and you wouldn't get any measurable increase in performance.

Comment: @meager : I know there is not much speed difference but it runs the CPU up a little more as it has to go find another file, read it, execute it, all as a sub-process. Okay not much difference, but everything helps when you plan to have many uses using the CMS servic, One server for quite a while. What you said is correct, but when you are surving thousands of webpages to thousands of people, the waisted time and CPU usage builds up. BTW: if you voted down for this reason, please remove the vote, as it is not related to the question, just my goal, I want small code, less includes, speed, etc :)

Comment: @James Even if you were serving *millions* of requests, this kind of optimization **does not matter**. The size of code has *nothing* to do with how fast it executes, and trying to save time by giving PHP less code to parse is the wrong thing to focus on. One more time, so there is no confusion: **small code, less includes != speed**

Comment: @meagar: While I totally agree with you on the whole code size issue I don't think you're right about the includes. The `[require|include]_once()` functions are notably slow compared to the regular ones; also, each file will have a stat call so that counts towards the disk I/O performance. I would say that if you literally have a thousand includes the difference will be noticeable. PS: I haven't actually benchmarked it, this is just my gut speaking for itself.

Comment: @Alix What do you mean, "the regular ones"? `include/require` instead of `include_once/require_once`? Regardless, The point is it's the wrong thing to optimize. Cramming your entire site into one file is the absolutely last thing you should do to speed up your site.

Comment: My CMS contains 2 ~10K files, a plugin directory (require_once), modulus (require_once), and a MySQL database containing: sites, pages, users, tracking, etc. I am already requiring every php file in /mods-enabled and /plugins/PLUGIN_NAME/pre-run.php,post-run.php for that sites settings, I have enough requires, for this plugin I will require it already, I would rather have one file in /plugins/openid/pre-run.php add in the needed php requirements, and also have in the database the Java-Script that I will add to make the client side add in the login, also pre-run.php will also include some html.

Comment: @James That sounds like a nightmare to maintain. You should be organizing your code into multiple files, ideally one per class. You gain nothing by keeping everything in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inspired by [lightopenid](https://gist.github.com/8db49baec4e0deb03e4f) and part of [phunction](https://github.com/alixaxel/phunction/blob/610f96b691cd645b218893f5e44dcc9d90478d58/_.php#L2468) *(depends on 5 other methods)*:**

```
public static function OpenID($id, $realm = null, $return = null, $verify = true)
{
    $data = array();

    if (($verify === true) && (array_key_exists('openid_mode', $_REQUEST) === true))
    {
        $result = parent::Value($_REQUEST, 'openid_claimed_id', parent::Value($_REQUEST, 'openid_identity'));

        if (strcmp('id_res', parent::Value($_REQUEST, 'openid_mode')) === 0)
        {
            $data['openid.mode'] = 'check_authentication';

            foreach (array('ns', 'sig', 'signed', 'assoc_handle') as $key)
            {
                $data['openid.' . $key] = parent::Value($_REQUEST, 'openid_' . $key);

                if (strcmp($key, 'signed') === 0)
                {
                    foreach (explode(',', parent::Value($_REQUEST, 'openid_signed')) as $value)
                    {
                        $data['openid.' . $value] = parent::Value($_REQUEST, 'openid_' . str_replace('.', '_', $value));
                    }
                }
            }

            return (preg_match('~is_valid\s*:\s*true~', self::CURL(self::OpenID($result, false, false, false), array_filter($data, 'is_string'), 'POST')) > 0) ? $result : false;
        }
    }

    else if (($result = self::XML(self::CURL($id))) !== false)
    {
        $server = null;
        $protocol = array
        (
            array('specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server', 'specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon', array('openid2.provider', 'openid2.local_id')),
            array('openid.net/signon/1.1', 'openid.net/signon/1.0', array('openid.server', 'openid.delegate')),
        );

        foreach ($protocol as $key => $value)
        {
            while ($namespace = array_shift($value))
            {
                if (is_array($namespace) === true)
                {
                    $server = strval(self::XML($result, sprintf('//head/link[contains(@rel, "%s")]/@href', $namespace[0]), 0));
                    $delegate = strval(self::XML($result, sprintf('//head/link[contains(@rel, "%s")]/@href', $namespace[1]), 0, $id));
                }

                else if (is_object($xml = self::XML($result, sprintf('//xrd/service[contains(type, "http://%s")]', $namespace), 0)) === true)
                {
                    $server = parent::Value($xml, 'uri');

                    if ($key === 0)
                    {
                        $delegate = 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select';

                        if (strcmp($namespace, 'specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server') !== 0)
                        {
                            $delegate = parent::Value($xml, 'localid', parent::Value($xml, 'canonicalid', $id));
                        }
                    }

                    else if ($key === 1)
                    {
                        $delegate = parent::Value($xml, 'delegate', $id);
                    }
                }

                if (ph()->Is->URL($server) === true)
                {
                    if (($realm !== false) && ($return !== false))
                    {
                        $data['openid.mode'] = 'checkid_setup';
                        $data['openid.identity'] = $delegate;
                        $data['openid.return_to'] = parent::URL($return, null, null);

                        if ($key === 0)
                        {
                            $data['openid.ns'] = 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0';
                            $data['openid.realm'] = parent::URL($realm, false, false);
                            $data['openid.claimed_id'] = $delegate;
                        }

                        else if ($key === 1)
                        {
                            $data['openid.trust_root'] = parent::URL($realm, false, false);
                        }

                        parent::Redirect(parent::URL($server, null, $data));
                    }

                    return $server;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
OpenID('https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id');
```

---

PS: I've updated the code I had previously posted because it was sub-optimal and prone to some bugs.

Comment: would this allow my users to login, with nothing but the above ??

Comment: @JamesM: Not really, you need to use the helper methods... I've added them to my answer. The whole thing only takes 5KB but you could optimize it further if you wanted to.

Comment: @Alfred: The code I posted has no external dependencies and is only 5KB.

Comment: @Alix take for example this line => ph()->Is->URL($url) === true. This ph() is not in the PHP language/library? => http://nl3.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=ph

Comment: @Alfred: `ph()` is from http://phunction.sf.net/. I forgot to replace it with the `URL()` function when I removed the dependencies. Should be fixed now. =)

Comment: get error when redirected back to ?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud&openid.response_nonce=2011-01-17T11:23:37Z_GyHLJ80RzOE_A&openid.return_to=http://westerveld.name/sopenid/test.php&openid.assoc_handle=AOQobUet1oiypwml2UMaOZQuneBD_Cnj5y-_2S00aiKV3sFcnUMbOraC&openid.signed=op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle&openid.sig=JOEEneeJxrGkFlblTn the question is how to output unique openid URL

Comment: @Alfred: Yup, me too. =\ I got it working with all of the major providers a few months ago and never touched it since then. I'll review this as soon as I get some free time.

Comment: @Alfred: The unique OpenID URL should be returned in openid_identity or openid_claimed_id, depending on the OpenID version.

Comment: @Alix good stuff :). BTW you don't have to look at for me(hurry) :). If I was going to use an openid library then openlightid would be good enough for me :P. Screw those 5 bytes ;). Although my favorite programming toolkit for me right now is node.js(javascript). It is really good and you should play with it if I were you ;)

Comment: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=www://sitegen.com.au/x.php&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.realm=www://sitegen.com.au/ I used the code above exactly and google gave me The page you requested is invalid. The reason is id.realm=www://s it works with http:// but then my server returns a "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error."

Comment: @JamesM: And with https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.return_to=http://sitegen.com.au/x.php&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.realm=http://sitegen.com.au/ ? I've no idea why www:// is showing up... You ran this at a default port like 80?

Comment: @JamesM: There are two instances of `www://` on the link generated, I tried replacing both and it seems to work. Regarding the `getservbyport()` "bug" I also have no idea...

Comment: read my new edits :) more edits, What about the: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Comment: BTW: I will tick the tick for this post when it decides to work :P

Comment: @JamesM: Bare in mind that I've never tested this method extensively, so it might be a good idea to do that yourself if you decide to use it. Anyway, I think I've nailed the problem: a while ago PHP replaced all dots on input `_REQUEST` keys with underscores. They seem to have fixed this now - try the updated function I'm about to post.

Comment: Use: `$_SERVER["HTTPS"] ? "https" : "http"` to find out what the http or https is..

Comment: Umm, Google is in an infinite reload loop. A form loads and does not go to my site. I think that the script is not stopping it from loggining in to google after we already have. Test it at http://sitegen.com.au/x.php

Comment: I reformatted your code and improved it a little, Please read my question edits Again :)

Comment: @JamesM: The loop bug is because of the `self::OpenID($_REQUEST['openid_identity'], false, false, false)` call. I don't have the time to review and fix this right now, sorry.

Comment: @JamesM: I've some ideas, but I've to test them.

Comment: btw: is not self:: no more, although it will be when i add it to my own class, that i will be using for this, :)

Comment: Humm, can you please give me your class that you are getting this code from?

Comment: @JamesM: I told you, this is based on lightopenid and part of phunction, so you either have to wait till I fix my implementation or base yours on lightopenid.

Comment: I may Read through the openid specs but again I may also wait for yours :)

Comment: BTW: you said it was inspired by lightopenid, and not based on lightopenid

Comment: @JamesM-SiteGen: I've posted an updated version, should put an end to the endless redirects.

Comment: @Alix Axel : Thanks and btw: I had to change several parent:: to self:: and change a few ph()->..-> self:: aswell, If you look above you will see my changes, Thank you Alix Axel.. :)

Comment: Now how do I get the openID user data? E-Mail, Name, unique openID code.

Comment: @JamesM-SiteGen: My method doesn't care for AX not SREG attributes so there is no way to get the user info. As for the unique OpenID identifier it's returned by the method itself (it either returns false or the user OpenID URL).

Comment: Okay, thanks, so do you know how I can now then go and get the users email at a minnimal??

Comment: You'd have to implement the request and parsing of AX and SREG attributes, but that would make the code significantly bigger. Lightopenid has good support for it.

Answer (score 2):

### Slim down Lightopenid

First of I really don't get your filesize limitation. I find it kind of b*llshit if you ask me....

You could make a call graph(use some sort of dead code detector) of lightopenid to see which functions(only a few are used) you are using. A lot of these big functions aren't used standard for example I believe you can remove the big function `protected function request_streams($url, $method='GET', $params=array())` on `line 198.` I also removed some other functions which aren't used when using it with `example-google.php` example. My final [lightopenid](https://gist.github.com/9742de21ca5f121deab9) class looks like this(I bet you can even eliminate more code when using call graph/dead code detector).

But now I got the filesize down to 9.8KB. If you compress it you can get it down even more. I got it down to your desired 10K mark, but now the code can not be read by humans anymore.

### Code searches:

You could also have a look at these resources/searches to see if any are lighter(I highly doubt that):

- https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=php&q=openid&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&x=17&y=33
- http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=openid+label:php&btn=Search+projects

Comment: Can still be red by humans just send it through a php formatter, see the first part of the question :) Also minimized php can still be read by yourself, its just not that easy.

Comment: BTW: I want it as small as i can get it so then I can improve it and add it to my cms as a plugin, The whole project has a goal to be slim and fast. Slim does not always mean fast, I do know but in my case it is, I have tried heaps of code vs my little code and it works great, I still may end up reading the openid spec and writing my own slimmer version, with only what i need.

Answer (score 1):

The slimmest openid implementation I know is [LightOpenId](https://github.com/Dreyer/LightOpenID)

It has got 30kb with comments, so if you run it through that formatter it gets much smaller

**EDIT**: I found a smaller one [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/15497.html) (just 6.6 kb after reformatting)

Comment: humm, re-formatted it again and got 17.4K, That is seaming better. :)

Comment: If you are looking for others, have a look at this website http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries